# Python list does not show all values

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Python application which stores URLS of sites in a List. The application works without fault but the application prints the list when the number of URL's in the list is 4038. Is there some kind of maximum number of string elements in which a List can store? Have i used up the memory on the stack?

Comment: No, in theory there is no limit to the number of strings you could store in a list. Also, I don't think Python lists are stored on a call stack. Could you add more details to your question? For example, it'd be useful to know what you're seeing printed.